# Bootstrap Checkbox Not Toggling

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-bootstrap

I am using a Bootstrap checkbox and a regular one. Why is the Bootstrap `Checkbox` failing to toggle, while the regular `input` field succeeds to toggle?

```
onChange = (evt) => {
    const target = evt.target;
    const name = target.name;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    });

    this.props.onChange({ name, value });
};
                    <input
                        name="unlimited"
                        type="checkbox"
                        checked={this.state.unlimited}
                        onChange={this.onChange} />
                    <Checkbox
                        name="unlimited"
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                        checked={this.state.unlimited}
                    >
                        UNLIMITED {this.state.unlimited.toString()}
                    </Checkbox>
```

**EDIT**
I made a bunch of mistakes when I originally posted code. Above is the corrected code.

**EDIT**
I am convinced this is a bug because Bootstrap JS library is interfering, [see here](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/2734#issuecomment-334736572).

Comment: It may be because they are doing something funny behind the scenes. Your onChange handler is expecting a native checkbox event. Looking at their docs, they return the value and not the event. You're going to have to write a slightly different onChange handler.

Comment: I've console.logged everything and native events work just fine, providing me with correct value when `type == checkbox`. The `checked` valued is toggling correctly between true and false.

Comment: Why are you updating state and then calling `this.props.onChange`?? You should be doing one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing to `checked` prop of the `Checkbox` a value from the parent via `props`. Are you sure you update the new state in the parent and passing a new prop again?

Here is an example using your code:

```js
const { Checkbox } = ReactBootstrap;

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      unlimited: false
    };
  }

onChange = (evt) => {
    const target = evt.target;
    const name = target.name;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    });
};

  render() {
    const { unlimited } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <input
            name="unlimited"
            type="checkbox"
            checked={this.state.unlimited}
            onChange={this.onChange} />
        <Checkbox
            name="unlimited"
            onChange={this.onChange}
            checked={this.state.unlimited}
        >
            UNLIMITED {this.state.unlimited.toString()}
        </Checkbox>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.31.3/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Edit**

> Any experience in overriding the bootstrap.js? it is on the global
>   template page of our app (PHP smarty)

I'm not a PHP expert but i guess you can conditionally render the script tag of `bootstrap.js`, So when you redirected to the page that use your `react` application just don't render the `<script>` tag.

Comment: See me edited code - I am updating state and have confirmed that.

Comment: You are now using `this.state.unlimited` for the `checked` prop but you never update it. you must update the Boolean value that you pass to the `checked` prop. See my example above

Comment: I am setting state with this.setState. What do you mean?

Comment: sorry i didn't notice that the input's name is `unlimited`. anyway i updated my example using your code exactly and it seems to work so there must have been some more code in your project that causes this behavior

Comment: I copied your code exactly. On github they are saying it might be bootstrap js file interfering, see link I added.

Comment: Aw are you loading `bootstrap.js` as well? indeed it can interfere, it has event listeners and handlers that can "swallow" and prevent bubbling of   events

Comment: Any experience in overriding the bootstrap.js? it is on the global template page of our app (PHP smarty)

Answer (score 1):

you have a controlled input - see https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

in this case, the checked is bound to your parent component's prop `fields={unlimited}`

you tells your parent via `onChange={}` that there's a new name and value - it will be up to it to `setState()` in a way that passes a new `fields.unlimited`

Eg, your stateful parent can be:

```
class Foo extends Component {
  state = {
    unlimited: false
  }

  onChange = (name, value) => this.setState({[name]: value})

  render(){
    return <MyOtherComponent fields={this.state} onChange={this.onChange} />
  }
}
```

if your component is stateful itself (looking at your handleChange), then you can convert to uncontrolled (https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) or bind to your local state if you sync it from props on mount and when it gets props.

Comment: I posted the wrong code, I have corrected it to only rely on local state